# Typescript Rank By Partition / Group

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting, rank

Let's say we have this initial array of object:

```
{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item1", price:1100, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item2",price:3200, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item3", price:1100, rank:0},

{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item1", price:2000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item2",price:2000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item3", price:3200, rank:0},

{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item1", price:3200, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item2",price:1100, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item3", price:2000, rank:0},
```

How to fill rank based on price property by it's item category compare to all vendor with same item.

Desired Result:

```
{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item1", price:1100, rank:1},
{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item2",price:3200, rank:3},
{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item3", price:1100, rank:1},

{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item1", price:2000, rank:2},
{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item2",price:2000, rank:2},
{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item3", price:3200, rank:3},

{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item1", price:3200, rank:3},
{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item2",price:1100, rank:1},
{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item3", price:2000, rank:2},
```

Comment: how do you calculate rank here? {vendor:"vendor1", item:"item2",price:3000, rank:3} oh is it price / 1000 ?

Comment: @gyc , i've modify the question

Comment: There is some data discrepancy. Supposed that you can fill the rank. Why did the price in before and after also changed?

Comment: Please check input data and also check output data.

Comment: Data you given is not right I think or you have some different algo

Comment: @Mukyuu, thank you, I forget to edit first array

Comment: So you took the lower price as the lower rank? Based on same item compared with other vendor?

Comment: @Mukyuu yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**STEPS:**

1. Get unique items.
2. Filter the whole array into small arrays of objects by unique item and sort by price.
3. Update the rank in every object in every separated array.
4. Concatenate them all back together.
5. Sort them by vendor to make it into the original order.

```js
let arr = [{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item1", price:1000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item2",price:3000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item3", price:1000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item1", price:2000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item2",price:2000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item3", price:3000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item1", price:3000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item2",price:1000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item3", price:2000, rank:0},]
let items = [...new Set(arr.map(o => o.item))]
let resultArr = []
items.forEach(item => {
  let filteredArr = arr.filter(o => o.item === item)
  filteredArr.sort((a,b) => (a.price > b.price) ? 1 : ((b.price > a.price) ? -1 : 0))
  for(let i = 0; i < filteredArr.length; i++){
    filteredArr[i].rank = i + 1
  }
  resultArr = resultArr.concat(filteredArr)
})
resultArr.sort((a,b) => (a.vendor > b.vendor) ? 1 : ((b.vendor > a.vendor) ? -1 : 0))
console.log(resultArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .rank was created based on price value

```js
var arr = [{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item1", price:1000, rank:0}, {vendor:"vendor1", item:"item2",price:1000, rank:0}, {vendor:"vendor1", item:"item3", price:1000, rank:0}, {vendor:"vendor2", item:"item1", price:2000, rank:0}, {vendor:"vendor2", item:"item2",price:2000, rank:0}, {vendor:"vendor2", item:"item3", price:2000, rank:0}, {vendor:"vendor3", item:"item1", price:3000, rank:0}, {vendor:"vendor3", item:"item2",price:3000, rank:0}, {vendor:"vendor3", item:"item3", price:3000, rank:0}];
arr.forEach(a => a.rank = (a.price/1000))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I've modify the question

Comment: ya but .your question and expected result not same price value is there any condition .Elaborate more

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the grouped `price`, sort them and apply the corrected index as `rank`.

```js
var data = [{ vendor: "vendor1", item: "item1", price: 1100, rank: 0 }, { vendor: "vendor1", item: "item2", price: 3200, rank: 0 }, { vendor: "vendor1", item: "item3", price: 1100, rank: 0 }, { vendor: "vendor2", item: "item1", price: 2000, rank: 0 }, { vendor: "vendor2", item: "item2", price: 2000, rank: 0 }, { vendor: "vendor2", item: "item3", price: 3200, rank: 0 }, { vendor: "vendor3", item: "item1", price: 3200, rank: 0 }, { vendor: "vendor3", item: "item2", price: 1100, rank: 0 }, { vendor: "vendor3", item: "item3", price: 2000, rank: 0 }],
    collection = data.reduce((r, o) => ((r[o.item] = r[o.item] || []).push(o.price), r), {});

Object.values(collection).forEach(a => a.sort((a, b) => a - b));

data.forEach(o => o.rank = collection[o.item].indexOf(o.price) + 1);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the array based on `item` and `price`. Then, loop through the sorted array and assign `rank` based on whether previous `item` is same as current `item`:

```js
const arr = [{vendor:"vendor1",item:"item1",price:1100,rank:0},{vendor:"vendor1",item:"item2",price:3200,rank:0},{vendor:"vendor1",item:"item3",price:1100,rank:0},{vendor:"vendor2",item:"item1",price:2000,rank:0},{vendor:"vendor2",item:"item2",price:2000,rank:0},{vendor:"vendor2",item:"item3",price:3200,rank:0},{vendor:"vendor3",item:"item1",price:3200,rank:0},{vendor:"vendor3",item:"item2",price:1100,rank:0},{vendor:"vendor3",item:"item3",price:2000,rank:0}]

const output = arr.sort((a, b) => a.item.localeCompare(b.item) || a.price - b.price)
  .map((o, i) => {
    const prev = arr[arr.length - 1]
    const rank = prev && prev.item === o.item
                   ? prev.rank + 1
                   : 1;
                   
    return { ...o, rank }
  })

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do using *map* function

```js
var arr = [{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item1", price:1000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item2",price:3000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item3", price:1000, rank:0},

{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item1", price:2000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item2",price:2000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item3", price:3000, rank:0},

{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item1", price:3000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item2",price:1000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item3", price:2000, rank:0}];
arr.map(a => a.rank = (a.price/1000))
console.log(arr)
```

Or using *forEach* function

```js
var arr = [{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item1", price:1000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item2",price:3000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor1", item:"item3", price:1000, rank:0},

{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item1", price:2000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item2",price:2000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor2", item:"item3", price:3000, rank:0},

{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item1", price:3000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item2",price:1000, rank:0},
{vendor:"vendor3", item:"item3", price:2000, rank:0}];
arr.forEach(a => a.rank = (a.price/1000))
console.log(arr)
```